# Error while running PySpark command

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark 1.4.1 in my Hadoop 2.6.0 and I tried to run the following PySpark command to count the number of lines. It throwing the following error. I am new for Spark and could not able to find the error.

Can anyone provide the solution.

```
>>> distFile = sc.textFile("/home/hduser2/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md")
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(213560) called with curMem=695185, maxMem=278019440
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10 stored as values in memory (estimated size 208.6 KB, free 264.3 MB)
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(19929) called with curMem=908745, maxMem=278019440
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_10_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 19.5 KB, free 264.3 MB)
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_10_piece0 in memory on localhost:60765 (size: 19.5 KB, free: 265.1 MB)
15/12/31 09:31:50 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 10 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2


>>> distFile.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 984, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 975, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 852, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 757, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser2/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1781)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is your file located on your local filesystem or hdfs?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 for reminding the file location. Now I am getting the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the file is in your local filesystem, but the error states it is looking for the file on HDFS.

`Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hduser2/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/README.md.`

Spark executes lazily, which means it won't actually read the file until it needs to, e.g. calling `count()`. That explains why the previous line doesn't error.

You can either move your file to that path in HDFS, or setup your SparkContext in local mode.

Comment: yes @cricket_007 I copied the file to hdfs. Now it is running succesfully. How to setup SparkContext in local mode.